# WP_User_Query::query was called incorrectly

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting this error message on my site how to solve this error

> Notice: Function WP_User_Query::query was called incorrectly. User queries should not be run before the plugins_loaded hook. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.1.) in /home3/middls9t/xyz.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5835

Need a Help for this wordpress error

Comment: Did you do this ___Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information___

Comment: I am also getting the same issue... but for time being I have set in wp-config.php  define( 'WP_DEBUG', false ); We have to find out why this issue occurred

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the loading of a plugin. Disable the plugins one after the other until you find the origin of the problem. (Start with the cache plugin)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).